# Values in Userdefaults getting reset on AppUpdate

Tags: objective-c

I am saving few user values in the userdefaults in the App. When I am updating the App, my values in the User Defaults are lost.

Thanks

Comment: maybe some other thing when wrong, as I know the data in UserDefault will not lost when update, it only lost when user delete Application

Comment: please provide the code where you save and load your values.

Comment: [userDefault setObject:@"temp1" forKey:@"email"];
   [userDefault setObject:@"1" forKey:@"user_id"];
   [userDefault synchronize];